# WCF security error

Tags: wpf, wcf

I can build some basic apps in wpf with wcf as a windows service, just basic things.  I am trying to make a wpf browser app and host it, along with wcf.

I am getting the following error when I try to get data from wcf:
'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Following is the code I used to access data:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Button1.Content = "asdasd"
        Dim serv As New ServiceReference1.IservClient
        Button1.Content = serv.DoWork
    End Sub
```

Code for app.config file for wpf browser app is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <!-- This section defines the logging configuration for My.Application.Log -->
            <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="FileLog"/>
                    <!-- Uncomment the below section to write to the Application Event Log -->
                    <!--<add name="EventLog"/>-->
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <switches>
            <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
        </switches>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="FileLog"
                 type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
                 initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
            <!-- Uncomment the below section and replace APPLICATION_NAME with the name of your application to write to the Application Event Log -->
            <!--<add name="EventLog" type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" initializeData="APPLICATION_NAME"/> -->
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Iserv" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:23072/serv.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Iserv" contract="ServiceReference1.Iserv"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_Iserv" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Code for wcf web config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Service code is:

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface Iserv

    <OperationContract()>
    Function DoWork() As String

End Interface

Public Class serv
    Implements Iserv

    Public Function DoWork() As String Implements Iserv.DoWork
        Return "ok"
    End Function

End Class
```

Could you please help me with this.  Thanks in advance.  Any advice on alternative methods are most welcome.

Source files are uploaded at 
https://skydrive.live.com/?id=d358d316fa2c3a37&sc=documents&uc=1&id=D358D316FA2C3A37%21135# 
file name is tiko.rar

Comment: Can you provide information if your application is running under partial trust. What is your project type of client and server. Where is your service hosted?

Comment: I dont know where the trust settings are, I just created a new Web browser wpf app and added a button, started wcf trmplate, and tried to access it by giving a service reference, that all.  The project is hosted on localhost, by pressing F5 key in visual studios.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check out this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcfprerelease/thread/02f6508b-d406-4354-8a18-3510fd7943fa/)

Also make sure that you can access the web service from a browser and also can see the wsdl in IE.

Comment: I saw the link and also followed as per this: [link]http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wcfinxbap.aspx however i am getting the same error only dont know why.

Comment: What is that you get when you access the webservice and its WSDL from IE.

Comment: I get an error message about the 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.